# Join a table that have multiple results, then merge into one column

Tags: php, mysql, database

*First of all, i know my question heading is little bit or more confusing so let me try to explain.*

I have 3 tables,

1. **Companies**
2. **company_branches**
3. **cities**

so with those tables, i want to select all from **companies** and join **company_branches** then join **cities**.

All **WITH JUST ONE SQL QUERY**, 
and i want to end up with a list of companies, and each company having it's branches (**array**) under a column called branches.

***See examples bellow.***

```
companies_table

  id    |   name
--------+-----------------------
  1     |  microsoft
--------+-----------------------
  2     |  facebook



company_branches_table

  id    |   company_id    | city_id
--------+-----------------+-------------
  1     |  1              | 3
--------+-----------------+-------------
  2     |  1              | 2
--------+-----------------+-------------
  3     |  2              | 1


cities

  id    |   name     
--------+-------------
  1     |  LA              
--------+-------------
  2     |  New york
--------+-------------
  3     |  Chicago
```

**Here is how i wanted my results to look like**

*in Json or associative array*

```
[
   {
     id       : 1,
     name     : microsoft,
     branches : [
                  {
                     id    : 2,
                     city_name : New york
                  },   
                  {
                     id    : 3,
                     city_name : Chicago
                  }
                ]
   },
   {
     id       : 2,
     name     : facebook,
     branches : [
                  {
                     id    : 1,
                     city_name : LA
                  }   

                ]
   }

]
```

I hope u'll understand.
thanks in advance

---

[Edit]

---

**Listed tables at the top**

Comment: What queries have you been trying? Where are you facing errors/issues?

Comment: You have to show effort of what you have tried.. you can't just show output without any effort

Comment: there is no error, i just want to improve the speed of my website by reducing multiple queries.. and for better practice.

Comment: May I ask why it has to be in one single query? I would do one query for fetching all companies in companies_table. Then one query for fetching all branches related to those companies.

Comment: @chawila are you using indexes? Thats where you should look first when it comes to improving speed. Have you checked your slow query logs?

Comment: Yeah, i know about indexing, but i just wanted to try something little bit advanced, so i didn't know where to start..

Comment: And i also wanted a way that i can use later when i'm filtering (by just adding 'where'), like looking for a companies that have a branch in a certain city and those that don't.

i know i can select them store in array then do the magic there, but i just thought there might be another way of doing it all in one query

Comment: I have a question regarding your database structure, a company cannot have more than one branch in one city?

Comment: select c.name,ci.name from companies_table c inner join company_branches_table cb on cb.company_id = c.id inner join cities ci on ci.id = cb.city_id

Comment: @SayedMohdAli
the company can have multiple branches in one city.  in a real database i have _branch_name_  in  **company_branch**  table. just that i was trying to sample up quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help

`SELECT ct.id,ct.name,group_concat(c.id, '->', c.name) AS branches FROM companies_table AS ct JOIN company_branches_table AS cbt ON ct.id = cbt.company_id JOIN cities AS c ON c.id = cbt.city_id GROUP BY ct.id`

Comment: Yeah, man it works fine.  it return the branches in comma separated string, which is ok because i can just explode them and get the array i want.

Thanks man..

Answer (score 0):

you can use group_concat()

```
    SELECT c.NAME                AS companyName, 
       Group_concat(ci.NAME) AS totalBranches 
FROM   companies_table c 
       INNER JOIN company_branches_table cb 
               ON cb.company_id = c.id 
       INNER JOIN cities ci 
               ON ci.id = cb.city_id 
GROUP  BY c.NAME
```

simple approach...

```
   SELECT c.NAME, 
       ci.NAME 
FROM   companies_table c 
       INNER JOIN company_branches_table cb 
               ON cb.company_id = c.id 
       INNER JOIN cities ci 
               ON ci.id = cb.city_id
```

both query is working properly tried in MySQL database...

Comment: works..
but i'll have to tick Rakhesh's answer because he answered first.. thanks though